# Freeswitch server getting INVITE request in ngrep but nothing in fs_cli

Tags: sip, freeswitch, lxc, opensips

I am trying to route the call from opensips server to freeswitch server. My freeswitch server is actually a container which i have created using 'lxc/lxd' and it is running CentOS.

When I route the call from opensips server to freeswitch server container i got the INVITE requests sip log in 'ngrep' but getting nothing in Freeswitch log as in nothing in fs_cli and my call is failing with the disposition 'SIP 408 - Request Timeout'

I have tried with routing the call from opensips server to other freeswitch server which is actually having a physical ip and not the container server and when I tried that, i am able to get the logs in freeswitch as in fs_cli.

Sip profile parameters auth-calls, auth-all-packets, aggressive-nat-detection set to true, there is no firewall or iptable rule between opensips and freeswitch servers. i can access the osips server from freeswitch server and vice versa.

So, what am i missing here. please suggest me something.

Comment: Where did you run ngrep? Inside FS container? Are you using DNAT to route the traffic from Server Interface to Container? Also try `sofia profile <profile name> siptrace on` in fs_cli

Answer (score 0):

In fs_cli, `sofia status` will show you on which IP address the SIP profile is bound. Probably it's not the address you're sending invites to.

Answer (score 0):

Your freeswitch server is not listening on the port with interface on
which you are sending. Just check out freeswitch profile on which
port and interface they are listening.